# what is the difference between warmup attribute in Fork and Warmup annotation in jmh?

Tags: jmh

I'm learning JMH benchmarking using this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness).

I noticed that there are 2 warmup related stuff for function benchMurmur3_128 in [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/jmh/src/main/java/com/baeldung/BenchMark.java).

so, I have question regarding the difference between warmup attribute in Fork annotation and Warmup annotation with iterations attribute?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With a JMH benchmark you run one or more forks sequentially, and one or more iterations of your benchmark code within each fork. There are two forms of warmup associated with this:

- At the fork level the **warmups** parameter to **@Fork** specifies how many warmup forks to run before running the benchmarked forks. Warmup forks are ignored when creating the benchmark results.
- The **@Warmup** annotation lets you specify warmup characteristics within a fork, including how many warmup iterations to run. Warmup iterations are ignored when creating the benchmark results.

For example:

- **@Fork(value = 3, warmups = 2)** means that 5 forks will be run sequentially. The first two will be warmup runs which will be ignored, and the final 3 will be used for benchmarking.
- **@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 55, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)** means that there will be 5 warmup iterations within each fork. The timings from these runs will be ignored when producing the benchmark results.
- **@Measurement(iterations = 4, time = 44, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)** means that your benchmark iterations will be run 4 times (after the 5 warmup iterations).

So the overall impact of the warmup settings shown above is that:

- Only the final three of the five forks will be used for the benchmark results.
- Only the final four iterations within each non-warmup fork will be used for the benchmark results.

That is why the JMH output below (which was run using those annotations against the benchmarked method) shows **Cnt 12** at the end of the run: 3 forks x 4 iterations = 12.

[image: jmharmup]

Comment: You are realy super great!! Thank you very much!!! Now only i understand the basics.

Comment: Please explain batchSize inside warmup `@Warmup(batchSize = 1000)`

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Regarding `batchSize`, I don't mean to be difficult but it would be more helpful to the community if you create your own question for that issue to attract a larger audience. If we discuss it here in the comments then hardly anyone else will see it, and the issue will not be searchable.

Comment: Thanks! But got the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527223/what-exactly-is-number-of-operations-in-jmh